# Finding the root of positive number using newton-raphson-method, R

Tags: r, function, math

So I have the following function, which finds the root of a function using Newton-raphson method. I think my issue is relatively simple: I want the function to find the *square root* of a given positive number, using the newton raphson medthod. Help?

```
# FUNCTION: 
newton <- function(f, delta = 0.0000001, x_0 = 2, n=1000){
  h = 0.0000001
  i = 1; x1 = x_0
  p = numeric(n)
  while (i <= n) { #while i is less than or equal to n(1000), continue iterations
    df.dx = (f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)) / h # 
    x1 = (x_0 - (f(x_0) / df.dx)) # output of original guess minus (f(x)/f´(x)) (formula for root finding)
    p[i] = x1 # counts iteration so we don't exceed 1000
    i = i+1 # same as ^
    if (abs(x1 - x_0) < delta) break # if output is less than delta: end iteration. Otherwise continue. (x1-x_0=if new value is below our threshold, stop)
    x_0 = x1
  }
  return(p[1: (i-1)]) #
}

############## TEST ###############
func1 <- function(x){
  x^5 - 7
}

newton(func1)

#VARIABLES are
#f = the function we input 
#delta = the accuracy threashold we are willing to accept 
#x_0 = our initial guess
#n = the number of iterations
#h = the distance from X1 to X0,this value much little ,the root much #closed.
#abs is a sys
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution :

```r
newton <- function(f, delta = 0.0000001, x_0 = 2, n=1000){
  h = 0.0000001
  i = 1; x1 = x_0
  p = numeric(n)
  while (i <= n) { #while i is less than or equal to n(1000), continue iterations
    df.dx = (f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)) / h # 
    x1 = (x_0 - (f(x_0) / df.dx)) # output of original guess minus (f(x)/f´(x)) (formula for root finding)
    p[i] = x1 # counts iteration so we don't exceed 1000
    i = i+1 # same as ^
    if (abs(x1 - x_0) < delta) break # if output is less than delta: end iteration. Otherwise continue. (x1-x_0=if new value is below our threshold, stop)
    x_0 = x1
  }
  return(list(result = x1, iterations = p[1:i-1]))
}

nthrootsub <- function(input, nth, x){ x^nth - input}

nthroot <- function(input, nth) {newton(function(x) nthrootsub(input, nth, x))}

############## TEST ###############

10^(1/5)
#[1] 1.584893

nthroot(10,5)
#$result
#[1] 1.584893

#$iterations
#[1] 1.725000 1.605878 1.585435 1.584894 1.584893 1.584893
```

Comment: What I would like it to do, is returning the root of a given number. Like:
newton(9) = 3
... but still showing the iterations

Comment: Something like this: https://hackernoon.com/calculating-the-square-root-of-a-number-using-the-newton-raphson-method-a-how-to-guide-yr4e32zo
But as an R algorithm

Comment: `func1 <- function(x){ x^2 - 9};newton(func1)` returns 3 with the above code

Comment: But it doesn't show the iterations that it went through to get to the root (the same way as the link I provided^). It just returns the root.

Comment: I've tried with the updated version. What I want it to do is to return just the square root of any given number, not a polynomial (as in the updated version). Am I making sense?

Comment: So the algorithm is so close at being there. The only thing is, that the input has to be a positive number only. So my goal is, that I should be able to write: ```newton(10)
#$result
#[1] 3.162277

#$iterations
$iterations
[1] 3.250000 3.163462 3.162278 3.162278 3.162278 ```

Comment: Awesome. The only problem is the 1.58 is not the squareroot of 10. And hey man, I really appreciate that you are taking the time to help!!

Comment: this is the fifth root : `nthroot(10,5)` , if you want square `nthroot(10,2)`. By the way, this looks like a homework. If this is the case, better to try to understand what is going on to learn from it ;-)

Comment: Ahh, of course, my bad. Again, thank you for your time!